Are there any example of practical application of counter machines?
I am currently working on a presentation over how counter machines are as effective as Turing machines. During my research, I found out that random access machines are an improved version of counter machines (with indirect addressing).
Is random access memory based on the RAM computational model? Are there any other real-life applications of the RAM computational model?

What does "this" refer to in "this computational model"?  What does "based on" mean?  What reading have you done, and what are your thoughts?  What does "these" refer to in "these machines"?

Hello! Sorry if my point wasn't clear: "this" refers to random access machines, "based on" means that RA (random access) memory originated from the concept of RA-machines (like modern-day computers originated from the Turing machine), and "these machines" designate register machines in general.

First of all, I have to let you know that I'm currently in my last year of high school, so I'm not an expert at all in computer science, in fact I would be quite a beginner. I've watched so far some videos on Youtube (Computerphile about counter machines) and read Wikipedia a lot, but unfortunately there aren't much content about this subject that is beginner-friendly, thus my question here.

Random access memory is not based on the RAM model.  It's the other way around: the RAM model was inspired by random access memory.
The RAM model is an abstraction of modern computers, which is useful for analysis of the running time of many algorithms.

Is this the only practical use of register machines in general?
